# SPRESENSE　dnnrt.bigin()を実行するとＬＣＤが表示できなくなる

Tags: spresense

ネットのソースコードを参考にSPRESENSEでジャンケンの手を認識できる機能を実装しています。

ＬＣＤの表示について、カメラの画像をリアルタイムでＬＣＤに表示する処理は正しく動作するのですが、そのソースコードでdnnrt.bigin()にてＮＮＣで生成したモデルを読み込むとＬＣＤが動きません。モデルは開いただけでＮＧでした。モデルが存在しない、開けないといった症状ではなさそうです。

別質問で学習モデルの形式がおかしいとSPRESENSEが動作しなくなるといった書き込みを見ましたがその類でしょうか？
またその場合、どのような学習モデルが不適切なのでしょうか？

ＬＣＤはILI9341を使用しています。

Answer (score 0):

最近、私がはまったのはブートローダとSDKの不一致です。ブートローダを最新のもの（1.4.0?）にアップデートされてみてはいかがでしょうか？

Comment: ありがとうございます。指摘の通りブートローダを現在最新のものにアップデートしましたが症状改善されませんでした。別質問にてみつけましたが、LCDやカメラを使うとnnbファイルのサイズが大きかった場合、メモリが足らずアプリがうまく起動しないことがあるようです。もう少し調査してみます。

Comment: カメラはかなりメモリを食います。特にプレビューと静止画を両方使っていると、それぞれ別メモリを確保するので、ヒープをかなり圧迫します。私は静止画は使わずに、プレビューのコールバックの中で認識処理を行うことでメモリを節約しています。ご参考になれば。

Comment: Cameraクラスのbegin()実行時に正しく処理しているか確認しました。結果学習モデル展開済みの場合はbegin()失敗していました。エラーコード確認したところ、やはりメモリが足らないのが原因だったようです。カメラ処理も初期化で躓いているので、何か手がないか一考してみます。ありがとうございました。